# Oracle APEX customizing page item required validation messages

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

I have a couple of required fields on the page that need to be selected/filled in when the user clicks Submit button. The fields are marked as required and I also use `Required` label template for them.

When the user clicks `Submit`, there is a popup message `Correct errors before saving`. How can i customize that message to display a list of required fields that needs to be filled in/selected?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the name of your item is P1_ITEM...

Right click on your item, click on create validation.

Settings:

- Name: Any name
- Type: Item is NOT NULL
- Item: P1_ITEM
- Always execute: Yes
- Error Message: Your custom message
- Display location: Inline with field and in Notification (or the option you prefer)
- Associated Item: P1_ITEM
- When Button Pressed: Your button

Finally, in your item, set Value Required: No.

Comment: that is not quite what I was looking for. I was talking about modifying built-in popup "Correct errors before saving" to list the fields that are required but not filled in

Answer (score 0):

I did this trick:

1. On Create/Save button, create a Dynamic Action.
2. Choose "Execute JavaScript Codes". Type this `$('[role="alertdialog"]>.ui-dialog-content').html("Your any messages");`
3. Usually, after you created a DA on a submit button, by default APEX will set the Action button Behavior to "Defined by Dynamic Action". So, you have to set it back to "Submit Page"

Good luck